# Binning continuous predictors, What is the best way?

Tags: binning

I want to run a binary logistic regression to understanding (modeling) factors affecting nest-site selection in a bird species.. I think it is better if I transform continuous variables to categorical variables, because for example Nest Height from the ground can have different effects in different ranges (different intervals); for example 0-200cm will have a negative effect in Nest-site selection while 200-250cm have a positive effect and it will be change in next ranges too + - - + + - + .. After running Binary logistic regression we will have a coefficient for each category instead of having a coefficient for a variable.

I am looking for a method where the cut points are not exactly in the data. I think it will be about distribution and density.. I think Equal probability histogram with Kernel density estimation is a good method for this purpose particularly when I can run a Pairwise comparison of means to know each category built properly or not, but only when I do Visual interpretation.. I am looking for a more scientific method which I will refer to in my article. Thanks.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is "+ - - + + - +" the pattern of the effect of height on selection? Why do you think this happens?  Is it several different effects interacting?

Comment: It's not exactly like that "+ - - + + - +"  I just gave an example... but I felt something like this in the environmental data

Comment: I think that is not my answer.. but thanks.

Comment: @MostafaAhmadi Why not? The accepted answer gives strong rationale about why this kind of binning is a poor strategy and how you can get the desired nonlinear behavior (the $++-+-+$ you desire) using alternative strategies.

Comment: Did you try to spline it?  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122212/logistic-regression-with-regression-splines-in-r

Comment: I think it is pretty much the consensus here and elsewhere among statisticians that binning is bad practice (especially "optimal" binning, which can very quickly devolve into p-hacking), and that splines are *much* better to capture nonlinearities. I would very much recommend you do look into splines, and if you then still believe you need binning, then please do edit this question and explain *why* splines are not the answer. Of course, if you have any questions about splines, you can post them here, or search in the [tag:splines] tag.

Comment: Thank you all.. You are right about using spline method.. But I am a new R user so I want to start learning about it now.