# With what argument can I use splines method in a binary logistic regression analysis?

Tags: regression, logistic, splines, regression-strategies

I want to run a binary logistic regression and I guess some variables have nonlinearities. So I want to use splines method to understand affect of each range in a continuous variable. When I 'guess' that nonlinearities it will enough to using splines method or I should run a 'test' on variables?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122212/logistic-regression-with-regression-splines-in-r. I don't think you should be running any tests!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Is this a good method if I run binary logistic regression for each continuous variable WITH and WITHOUT splines, then I compare their AIC and WALD p-values, and then determine if it's better to use the splines method or not?